# Reference request: Tensor Product of $m$ $SU(N)$ algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, lie-groups

I'm working on quantum mechanics of linear $SU(N)$ chain of sites.

Specifically, I would like to study a Tensor product of $m$ Lie algebras
$\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{u}(N)$

$$
V\in SU(N)\\
W = V\otimes^m \subset SU(N^m)
$$
Has such a study been undertaken before ? How would one approach this topic ?
If one assumes standard knowledge of representation theory/group theory.

Comment: [So the $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ ***is*** a lie (algebra)...](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=3340#comic)

Comment: [To lie or not to lie (algebra)...](https://xkcd.com/246/)